# UVC (USB Video Device Class) control of pan/tilt on OS X

Tags: macos, usb, hardware, webcam, iokit

I am trying to modify an existing application that talks to a standard USB video device class webcam (a Logitech BCC950 camera) over USB on OS X.

The device (a conferencing webcam) is compliant with USB's "Video Device Class" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class). [I have provided a link](http://phoboslab.org/log/2009/07/uvc-camera-control-for-mac-os-x) to some source code that allows controlling saturation and white balance of the picture using the webcam's hardware and the VDC specification.

I now want to control the pan/tilt function of this webcam. This is called "CT_PANTILT_ABSOLUTE_CONTROL" in the specification. How do I do this?

[This site](http://phoboslab.org/log/2009/07/uvc-camera-control-for-mac-os-x) has some example code for controlling the gain, exposure and a handful of other settings with OS X's IOKit.

The aim would be to make an application similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U10OqVzoHbw that is controllable using a web interface.

I want to send new parameters for the CT_PANTILT_ABSOLUTE_CONTROL command, to control the pan of the camera.

Additionally, in the documentation, VC_PROCESSING_UNIT is listed as 0x05, but in the source, it's listed as 0x02. Also, other sources such as the [Linux UVC headers](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/media/video/uvc/uvcvideo.h) define it as 0x05.

In the [UVC specifications](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs), this is listed under 4.2.2.1.14 PanTilt (Absolute) Control, however, I am unclear of the unit & selector codes that are required to get this information.

I would love to get some help for the commands & code that needs to be written so that this application will work in OS X with IOKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a friend, we have found this: https://github.com/kazu/UVCCameraControl

It is a modified version of the code that I linked to in my question, however, it seems to have support for Pan & Tilt.

I have as of yet not tried it, but quickly looking at the code, it seems to support everything that I need.

Comment: Did you get this code running and/or finish your code? I'm looking into using the absolute pan/tilt with a Jetson Nano, so I'm looking for examples to implement in Linux.

Comment: @Greenonline yeah, I did. Sadly, the code was for an internal video chat organisation at a previous job, and I don't have the code. That being said, all the code was very Mac-specific.
If you want to implement on Linux, it's not too hard. These links will help:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/media/kapi/v4l2-subdev.html
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/68a32ba14177d4a21c4a9a941cf1d7aea86d436f/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvc_driver.c#L1090-L1166